# Python: Grabbing the width and height of image from url

Tags: python, regex

A 3rd party app saves images in such naming format where q85 is the quality, AAxBB means width and height:

```
62620587b.jpg.122x132_q85.jpg -> 122x132

62620587c.jpg.143x85_q85.jpg -> 143x85

6768113_sa.jpg.122x132_q85.jpg -> 122x132

Toshiba_50-Inch_Side.jpg.150x150_q85.jpg -> 150x150
```

What is the clever way to split width and height numbers from such string urls?

Comment: what about  re.findall("[\d]+x[\d]+",variable_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall("[\d]+x[\d]+",variable_string)
```

but it will produce an duplication because the line `62620587b.jpg.122x132_q85.jpg -> 122x132` contain the AAxBB twice ,,, you can make an method that delete the duplication

Comment: I think the `-> 122x132` is not actually part of the input but is just supposed to show the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to do it:

```
/(\d+)x(\d+)/
```

What the problem?